# getJson function printing out an empty list when it takes in an user input

Tags: sql, json, python-3.x, tkinter, better-sqlite3

I am creating a program where the user selects a city from a drop down menu in data.py* and it prints out data for that city. After the user selects the city, it goes into a getJson function in backend.py* that takes the user's selected city as an argument. The getJson function extracts data from a SQLite3 table and returns a json string which is a list containing a dictionary with the city as the key and the data as the values. After I got the code in getJson function to work in it's own module, by hard coding the city argument, it prints out the correct json string output. However, when I try running getJson from the menu module, it prints out the correct user inputed city but an empty list with no dictionary when I try to run getJson through that UI module.

Here is my code for creating the SQLite3 table and the getJson function in the backend module:

```
class Backend:
    def sql(self):``
    self.cur.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS C(City TEXT, Year TEXT, Value TEXT)')
    for record in self.cities:
        self.cur.execute(
            '''INSERT INTO C (City, Year, Value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)''',
            (record[0], record[1], record[2]))


    def getJson(self, userInput):
       self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
       self.cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM C WHERE City='%s'""" % userInput)
       records = self.cur.fetchall()
       #self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM C")^^^this line
       with open('Cities.json', 'w') as fh:
           city_as_dict = [{'City': city[0], 'Year': city[1], 'Value': city[2]} for city in records]
           json.dump(city_as_dict, fh, indent=3)
        with open('Cities.json', 'r') as fh:
           self.json_string = json.load(fh)
        fh.close()
        print(self.json_string)
        return self.json_string
```

And here is the code for the menu and function that takes user's input in the data module:

```
from backend import Backend

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
      self.b = Backend()
      self.OPTIONS =self.b.cities

      self.master = Tk()
      self.variable = StringVar(self.master)
      self.variable.set(self.OPTIONS[0])
      self.city = ""

      w = OptionMenu(self.master, self.variable, *self.OPTIONS)
      w.pack()

      button = Button(self.master, text="OK", command=self.ok)
      button.pack()

   def ok(self):
      self.city = self.variable.get()
      print(self.city)
      self.b.getJson(self.city)
```

Ex Output When Running backend.py With Hardcoded City:

[{Chicago: 2015, 100}, {Chicago: 2016, 200}, {Chicago: 2017, 300}]

Ex Output When Running data.py With Chicago Selected From Menu:

Chicago
[]

Also an error I get is, when I run backend.py with (self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM C")) this line of code, it works perfectly fine, but when I run from data.py, it gives a database is locked error.
I'm guessing most of my mistakes are some sort of syntax mistake, but I cannot seem to figure out what part is wrong with my code. Any feedback or corrections would be really helpful. Thanks guys!!

Comment: is tkinter being asked about here, or is the problem about fetching the data? I don't see how tkinter is relevant to the problem being asked about. Won't you have this same problem no matter what front-end technology you use?

Comment: Hi Bryan, sorry if I wasn't clear enough about what my problem is, but yes I am having problems with fetching data either from wrong way of calling methods from another module, my Tkinter menu not being set up correctly, or due to not creating the json string correctly. To cut it short, I get the correct output when I run the code from backend.py but output is an empty string when I run from data.py. I just want some advice on what looks wrong with my code that might cause this to happen.

Comment: It's still not very clear. If you call `self.b.getJson` and you give it a valid city, does it return the right thing? If it does, then the problem is that you're not passing in a valid city. Have you examined `self.city` immediately prior to calling the function?